# Python combination script

Tags: python, math, combinations

I'm working on a project. I have different flooring materials and different prices:

Here's the price of all different types of floor per square foot:

```
1.00, 1.40, 1.43, 1.58, 2.09, 2.97, 3.25, 3.99, 4.12, 4.29, 4.48
```

I have my house which has different rooms with different square footage, here are the areas of each room:

```
896, 132, 132, 120, 219, 88, 189, 41
```

my budget is `3500`. I want to make a python script that will run through all possible combinations and find the combination that will use the most of my budget without going over. It must use at least unique prices and must not exceed my budget.

I tried

```py
import itertools

numbers = [1.00, 1.40, 1.43, 1.48, 2.09, 2.97, 3.25, 3.99, 4.12, 4.29, 4.48]
target = 3500

result = [seq for i in range(len(numbers), 0, -1)
          for seq in itertools.combinations(numbers, i)
          if sum(seq) == target]

print(result)
```

but doesn't work because it thinks each number can only happen once. I'm not sure how to fix it.

Comment: import itertools

numbers = [1.00, 1.40, 1.43, 1.48, 2.09, 2.97, 3.25, 3.99, 4.12, 4.29, 4.48]
target = 3500

result = [seq for i in range(len(numbers), 0, -1)
          for seq in itertools.combinations(numbers, i)
          if sum(seq) == target]

print(result)

Comment: i am not seeing where you have involved the `square footage` in your code ?

Comment: yeah no labels needed

Comment: also i figured out my the py script im using doesnt work, becuase it thinks each number can only happen once not sure what to do to fix it

Comment: I would have thought that you would have to do a calculation for `price x square_footage` somewhere in your script ??

Comment: not sure how to add that

Comment: any change you know how to add that to code

Answer (score 0):

The most important bit of code is the following:

```
combinationsX = itertools.combinations_with_replacement(price, 8)
```

It generates a combination of **prices** that can fit into **8 slots**.
These slots are used to do the calculation:
eg.

```
(1.58*896)+(1.58*132)+(1.58*132)+(1.58*120)+(1.58*219)+(2.09*88)+(4.12*189)+(4.12*41) = $3499.94
```

Then it is just a matter of dealing with the specifications and conditions. For example,

- ensuring that there are at least **3 unique prices**
- The price does not go over the **target of $3500**
- And storing the combination closest to the target.

Here is the code:

#### Code:

```
import itertools

def sum_flooring(values, printResult="no"):
    square_footage = [896, 132, 132, 120, 219, 88, 189, 41]
    result = [x * y for x, y in zip(values, square_footage)]
    
    # Used to print the calculation
    if printResult == "yes":
        text ="+".join([(f"({x}*{y})") for x, y in zip(values, square_footage)])
        print(text, f"= ${sum(result):.2f}")  
          
    return sum(result)
    
target = 3500
min_diff = 3500
price = [1.00, 1.40, 1.43, 1.58, 2.09, 2.97, 3.25, 3.99, 4.12, 4.29, 4.48]
combinationsX = itertools.combinations_with_replacement(price, 8)

for c in combinationsX:
    if len(set(c))>2:
        total_cost = sum_flooring(c)
        if total_cost <= target:
            diff = target - total_cost
            if diff < min_diff:
                min_diff = diff
                final_combination = c

# Show the combination of prices used
print("Combination: ", final_combination)

# Show Calculation
print("-----------------------------------------------------------------")
sum_flooring(final_combination, printResult="yes")

# Show how much money is remaining
print(f"Difference from target = ${min_diff:.2f}")
```

#### Output:

```
Combination:  (1.58, 1.58, 1.58, 1.58, 1.58, 2.09, 4.12, 4.12)
-----------------------------------------------------------------
(1.58*896)+(1.58*132)+(1.58*132)+(1.58*120)+(1.58*219)+(2.09*88)+(4.12*189)+(4.12*41) = $3499.94
Difference from target = $0.06
```